# How to programmatically set proxy settings

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, proxy

I'm trying to change the proxy settings on OS X (10.9 and beyond) programmatically. The only solutions I've found so far seem to involve setting the proxy settings individually on each interface. For completeness, they also seem to implicitly involve monitoring interfaces coming and going, so that the settings could be added as interfaces are added.

I've written some test code with `SCDynamicStoreSetValue()`, which appears to do the right thing (i.e. the right stuff shows up if I verify with scutil). However, as soon as I change interfaces (i.e. plug in/unplug a wired interface), the settings go away.

I also looked at modifying `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`, but that (also) seems to require updating on a per-interface basis, among other problems.

Is there a global/default setting, whereby if the `per-interface` setting isn't set, the system will fall back to that? If so, how do I get/set it?

Comment: Hey have u find any solution on this ?

Comment: Hi, you can use below command to  update the same :
    From the terminal you can hit the :
     networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi 127.0.0.1 14201

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file and run from the terminal is same :Batch file creation as below:

```
 #! /bin/bash

 export PATH=/usr/local/share/dotnet:$PATH 

 networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi 127.0.0.1 14201
 networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 14201

 networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Wi-Fi  127.0.0.1 14201
 networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Ethernet  127.0.0.1 14201
```

Save the file with no extension and run below command with file path

```
  chmod +x filepath
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below command to  update the same 
    use terminal to hit

```
networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi 127.0.0.1 14201

networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 14201

networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Wi-Fi  127.0.0.1 14201

networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Ethernet  127.0.0.1 14201
```